# Editing polygons in leaflet.js and leaflet.snap

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I'm using leaflet.snap (http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Snap/) which lets me snap points to lines when drawing a polygon - just what I need. BUT I'm having a hard time trying to get set the polygons to be editable.

Here's my code, which uses Leaflet.Snap, and allows drawing but not editing of a polygon. Any help getting the polygons editable is much appreciated.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet Snap Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
       <style>
     .leaflet-editing-icon.marker-snapped {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
 </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Snap/Leaflet.draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css" />
    <script src="http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Snap/Leaflet.draw/dist/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    <script src="http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Snap/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/dist/leaflet.geometryutil.js"></script>
    <script src="http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Snap/leaflet.snap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map" style="height: 500px; width: 800px"></div>
<script>
var theTileLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2013 OpenStreetMap contributors',
});
var map = L.map('map').setView([45.4835656, -122.7332588], 12).addLayer(theTileLayer);
    var guideLayers = new Array();
    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);
 var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
position: 'topright',
draw: {
    polyline: false,
    polygon: {
        shapeOptions: {
            color: '#009900'
        }
     },
    circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
    rectangle: false,
    marker: false
      },
    edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems, //REQUIRED!!
    remove: true
    }
        });
    map.addControl(drawControl);


// Editing lines works fine on the sample (http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Snap/) but not below.

   drawControl.setDrawingOptions({
        polygon: { guideLayers: guideLayers, snapDistance: 15 },
   });

    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var layer = e.layer;
        map.addLayer(layer);
        guideLayers.push(layer);

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you get this working?  I am having similar problems.

Comment: The answer from Dhrumil worked for me, although I need to revise some code because I think the Snap code changed since I started using it.

Answer (score 0):

It's just you missed to add layer to drawnItems while any drawing is complete. Just replace "map" by "drawnItems" in your code like following and it will work:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var layer = e.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    guideLayers.push(layer);

});
```

Enjoy!